# Search for unanswered question with my tags that older than 12 hours

Tags: support, tags, search, unanswered-questions, time

Is there a way to search for questions (is:question) which are

- unanswered (answers:0)
- have my tags ("tags:mine" would be fine, but it seems not to be allowed)
- have been asked 12 hours ago or before

Rational: I want to skip trivial questions and I want to avoid the races which occur to answered these questions.

Comment: I have a similar request.  I want to avoid the "first post" rush to answer new questions, so my current approach is to go to "Interesting questions" (the default) and scroll down until I get to questions answered 1 hour ago and start reading from there.  Can we make this question into a feature request, or should we raise a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no such filter like *12 hours old questions* in the search page. Also there is no option like *tags:mine*. You have to add tags manually.
E.g. [answers:0 [sql]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0%20%5Bsql%5D)

If you want to search for questions elder than xx hours click on [newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0%20%5Bsql%5D). Here you will get the latest question first.

Comment: Is my rational acceptable? Which option do I have no? Is there a way to post a feature request?

Comment: @Michael - What is your criteria for *trivial* questions?

Comment: I have no clear cut criteria. I just want to avoid questions which can be answered within seconds after asking. I would prefer to focus on questions which need some research. Is this requirement ok?

Comment: @Michael - I don't think so. Because how can system decide the quality of the question?

Comment: No, not system but statistics: a question which is unanswered since 12 hours needs probably some research to be answered, I think.

Comment: Fair enough. But as I already mentioned in the answer, we can search through [newest tab](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0%20%5Bsql%5D).

Answer (score 2):

The filter `-created:1d` [is available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). Do you really need it to be 12 hours, or is 24 good enough?

Comment: Thank you! Of course 24 hours are good!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want. But you can go to the Unanswered questions, and then to the "my tags" tab.

There should be something you can answer.

Comment: But it shows questions with **no upvoted answers**

Comment: Yes, and I could move forward and skip all question asked between now and 12 hours before :) but this is not the solution I was looking for. A separate and configurable tab ("serious question" ;) would be great ... maybe only available if one has a certain amount of reputation.